# Illustrator: how to create a triangle with one round corner

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder, corners

How do I round one corner of a triangle? Dragging 1 widget rounds all corners and holding down Alt/Option doesn't help.

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: And what version?

Comment: Excuse me, forgot to mention. Using Illustrator trial version activated a few hours ago.
Yes I'm a complete noob but I know how to follow instructions and sadly this 1 little detail is not working and driving me scatty.

Comment: Select only the point you need to change with the direct selection tool (white arrow)

Comment: That still moves all corners :(

Comment: I entered a radius value in dialogue box and that has done the trick. Been trying to drag widgets unsuccessfully for over 90 mins. Don't understand why I can't drag a rounded corner.

Thank you for trying to help. I super appreciate it.

Comment: As a new user, you probably want to read the introductory [tour] some time. Please use **[edit]** to add additional details to your question - do not scatter them in comments.

Comment: @Andosan start by describing what exactly you are doing. With pictures. And use the **[edit button](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/84153/edit)** not comment fields

Comment: I select one corner with **A** (shortcut tool) and drag the widget.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you mentioned that it was a "Illustrator trial version activated a few hours ago", which would be Illustrator CC 2017.1. In this version what you were doing (dragging one widget) was the proper way, but you need to select only one of them instead of all of them. You can do this with the black arrow (**V**) by selecting the object and holding **CTRL/CM**. This will make the "widgets" visible, as circles. While still holding **CTRL**, if you click on the widget for the corner you want rounded it will turn solid. This means it is selected and can be individually manipulated.
[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

make a fresh triangle (you can do it with the polygon shape tool, click art board and enter 3 sides)

Make sure it is unselected. Drag a box around 1 point with the white arrow.

Now convert anchor to round and adjust the handles (the hard way) or on my new version of illustrator CC when I select a corner with the direct selection tool (white arrow) it shows a "Corners" tool in my top bar. I can increase and decrease the amount of roundedness on 1 tip of my triangle with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hard worker's solution. Nothing clever, but no need to tinker with nearly invisible - that's the Bezier handles in a sharp corner.

[image]

**Addendum for a non-constructive comment:**
Having a 2010 version of Ai and no interest for programming (did it for work as an Assembly coder) I show in one image, what it takes to position the wanted rounding circle (=the red one) tangentially by relying on Ai's smart quide snapping. Anybody who is familiar with elementary plane geometry sees immediately the idea:

[image]

Comment: You dont have to eyeball this. You can draw a bisector line between the two edges. The center of the circle lies on this line. You can then find the postion simply by measuring with 2 lines. If you ask the question then i will explain.

Comment: @joojaa Yes - well presented in Kalle Väisälä's Book of Elementary Geometry. But I wanted one modest size screenshot to be enough.. But you get the question.

Comment: Well yes its known mathematics from at least the age of Euclides, so been known a few thousand years. But there is rarely need to do this as even in versions that dont have this function you can just use the rounding script of SHS anyway i need to go to sleep now.